# Config split settings file generated into split directory

Tags: configuration

Drupal 8.7
I have a multisite split. The `config_split.config_split.<sitename>.yml` files are supposed to go into the `config/default` directory. For some reason when updating a split on one of my sites, instead of updating the existing file in that location, it creates a new file in the config/sitename directory. It only does it on this one site. When I compare the newly generated file to the one for that site in the default directory, only the new changes are different. The rest is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this was caused by the actual config split config item being listed in the graylist of the file... So, in `config/default/config_split.config_split.www.yml` was the entry for `config_split.config_split.www` in the graylist which then made them "different" and a new file would be created (if we had deleted it) or updated in the `config/default/www` directory. Since that entry was removed, it has behaved as it should.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the $config_directories array in the settings.php/settings.local.php files.

It might be a good idea to explicitly set it via config as per https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/configuration-management/changing-the-storage-location-of-the-sync-directory:

```
$config_directories[CONFIG_SYNC_DIRECTORY] = '../config/sync';
```